# opengl draw in 2D coordinates instead of vertex coordinate system

Tags: c++, opengl, math, coordinates, geometry-shader

how can i draw in 2D coordinates instead of vertex coordinate system, as this =>

```
drawPoint(50 , 100 ,  0.01f);
```

[image]

this is my code , a background texture and a point

```
static void Draw(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH ) / 300.0;
    double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT ) / 300.0;
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glOrtho( -1 * w/2, 1 * w/2, -1 * h/2, 1 * h/2, w/2, -h/2);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-w/2.f, -h/2.f,  0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( w/2.f, -h/2.f,  0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( w/2.f,  h/2.f,  0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-w/2.f,  h/2.f,  0.0f);
    glEnd();

  drawPoint(50 , 100 ,  0.01f);
  glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

the function DrawPoint => draws circles

```
void drawPoint(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat radius){
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    int i;
    int triangleAmount = 20; //# of triangles used to draw circle

    //GLfloat radius = 0.8f; //radius
    GLfloat twicePi = 2.0f * 3.1415;

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex2f(x, y); // center of circle
        for(i = 0; i <= triangleAmount;i++) {
            glVertex2f(
                    x + (radius * cos(i *  twicePi / triangleAmount)),
                y + (radius * sin(i * twicePi / triangleAmount))
            );
        }
    glEnd();
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

So I don't know if I have to change the DrawPoint function.

UPDATE : this is my main source

```
 glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(widthX, heightY);
    glutCreateWindow("prg");
    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
    glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyPressed);
    glutKeyboardUpFunc(keyUp);
    texture[0] = SOIL_load_OGL_texture 
    (
        "img.jpg",
        SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
        SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT
    );
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
    glHint(GL_POINT_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glutMainLoop();
```

UPDATE 2 :

if in this way is impossible, is there a method that transform an x and y into a vector ?, so for example :

DrawPoint(VectConvert(50),VectConvert(100),0.01f);

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is right answer. I edited your code, try this:

```
static void Draw(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 

    // You divided your window width and height by 300 which seems to be wrong
    double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // Create ortho 2d
    // The last two parameters are near and far planes
    // Since you are using only 2D you should keep them at 0.0 and 1.0
    glOrtho( -1 * w/2.0, 1 * w/2.0, -1 * h/2.0, 1 * h/2.0, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    // Mirror Y axis 
    glScalef(1, -1, 1);
    // Now your coordinate system starts at center of your window
    // You need to move it to the left top corner
    glTranslatef(-(w/2.0f), -(h/2.0f), 0.0f);

    texture[0] = SOIL_load_OGL_texture // load an image file directly as a new OpenGL texture
    (
        "img.jpg",
        SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
        SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT
    );

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    // You need also to mirror your Y coordinates for texture
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(0.0f , 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(w    , 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(w    , h   , 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(0.0f , h   , 0.0f);
    glEnd();
    drawPoint(50 , 100 ,  0.01f);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Also, do not load your texture from file every frame. It is overkill for your GPU.

Comment: "Also, do not load your texture from file every frame. It is overkill for your GPU." Quite the opposite, the GPU will be bored to death by this.

Comment: But the real problem with this answer is that you did get the transformation order wrong. Also putting that into modelview is not the best idea.

Comment: @NPLS: I added an answer myself. There is no need to use a composition of three transforms if it can be achieved by a single one, altough one of course could get that right, too. But I'm actually too lazy to do the math here...

Comment: Whoops, sorry guys. I did not noticed the wrong transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Just set an ortogonal projection as you need it:

```
 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
 glLoadIdentity();
 glOrtho( 0, w, h, 0, -1, 1);
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
 glLoadIdentity();
```

Please note a few things here:

- This assumes that `w` and `h` are actually the width and height of your viewport.
- I put this into the `GL_PROJECTION` matrix. That is where this stuff belongs. (Although it might not be critical in your use case).
- I set the near and far planes to -1 and 1 respectively. I don't know what you actually will need, but your values didn't make any sense.
- That will set up a coordinate system where the pixel *centers* are actually exactly between two integer values, and integer values denote the middle between two adjacent pixels, so (0,0) will be the top left *corner* of the top left pixel, and (w,h) the bottom right corner of the bottom left pixel.
- You also could set up a mapping that maps the integers to the pixel centers, like `glOrtho(-0.5, w-0.5, h-0.5, -0.5, -1, 1)`. Now (0,0) is the center of the top left pixel, and (w,h) is outside the screen, (w-1,h-1) is the center of the bottom right pixel.

Comment: with this  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
 glLoadIdentity();
 glOrtho( 0, w, h, 0, -1, 1);
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
 glLoadIdentity(); (or glOrtho(-0.5, w-0.5, h-0.5, -0.5, -1, 1)) the image texture is not centered is at left corner (top) , my problem is to make this coordinate system but maintain the texture in background , and for that i need  glOrtho( -1 * w/2, 1 * w/2, -1 * h/2, 1 * h/2, w/2, -h/2); for center my texture on the window

Comment: @NPLS: You cannot have ot both ways - at the same time. YOu can of course swithc the projection matrix inbetween draw calls (there are some pitfalls like the depth buffer, though). So either use the same coordinate system for both things, and adjust the vertex coords accordingly, or switch inbetween.

Comment: @NPLS: in your case, it might be enought to just add the code block I wrote in my answer to the start of your `DrawPoint` function. But I don't think that this will be the optimal place, especially if you call this multiplem times per frame.

Comment: with your code the texture background perfect fills the entire window but the point doesn't appears

Comment: @NPLS: This is impossible to diagnose without seeing more code.

Comment: if i pu drawPoint(0.5f , 0.4f ,  0.01f); the circle appears but if i put drawPoint(50, 100 ,  0.01f); it doesn't show me nothing